# How to use nested arrays to store a cell's row and column numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple piece of code written which basically scans through column A, detects for a condition and once the condition is met in a row, it copies the cell in column B of the same row into an array. I was hoping someone could help me make a nested array which would not only store the value in column B but also its rowcount. here is what i have so far, any help is appreciated.

```
Dim col2 As Range
Dim cell2 As Excel.Range
Dim rowcount2 As Integer
Dim ii As Integer

ii = 0
rowcount2 = DataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set col2 = DataSheet.Range("A1:A" & rowcount2)
Dim parsedcell() As String
Dim oldarray() As String

    For Each cell2 In col2

        If cell2.Value <> Empty Then
            parsedcell = Split(cell2.Value, "$")
            sheetName = parsedcell(0)

                If sheetName = DHRSheet.Name Then

                    Dim oldvalue As Range
                    ReDim Preserve oldarray(ii)
                    Set oldvalue = DataSheet.Cells(cell2.Row, 2)

                    oldarray(ii) = oldvalue.Value

                    ii = ii + 1

                End If

      End If

    Next
```

Comment: May I see a sample workbook? Also what is the value of any given `cell2.Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a two dimensional array.  Use one dimension for the value and the other for the row.  Here's an example

```
Sub GetArray()

    Dim vaInput As Variant
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim aOutput() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lCnt As Long

    'Define the range to test
    Set rRng = DataSheet.Range("A1", DataSheet.Cells(DataSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 2)
    'Put the values in that range into an array
    vaInput = rRng.Value

    'Lopo through the array
    For i = LBound(vaInput, 1) To UBound(vaInput, 1)
        'Skip blank cells
        If Len(vaInput(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            'Test for the sheet's name in the value
            If Split(vaInput(i, 1), "$")(0) = DHRSheet.Name Then
                'Write the value and row to the output array
                lCnt = lCnt + 1
                'You can only adjust the second dimension with a redim preserve
                ReDim Preserve aOutput(1 To 2, 1 To lCnt)
                aOutput(1, lCnt) = vaInput(i, 2) 'write the value
                aOutput(2, lCnt) = i 'write the row count
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    'Output to see if you got it right
    For i = LBound(aOutput, 2) To UBound(aOutput, 2)
        Debug.Print aOutput(1, i), aOutput(2, i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim col2 As Range
Dim cell2 As Excel.Range
Dim rowcount2 As Integer
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim p As Integer
p = 0

rowcount2 = DataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set col2 = DataSheet.Range("A1:A" & rowcount2)
Dim parsedcell() As String


    For Each cell2 In col2

        If cell2.Value <> Empty Then
            parsedcell = Split(cell2.Value, "$")
            sheetName = parsedcell(0)

                If sheetName = DHRSheet.Name Then
                    Dim subarr(1) As Variant
                    Dim oldvalue As Range

                    ReDim Preserve arr(p)


                    Set oldvalue = DataSheet.Cells(cell2.Row, 2)

                    subarr(0) = oldvalue.Value
                    subarr(1) = cell2.Row
                    arr(p) = subarr
                    p = p + 1

                    'MsgBox (oldvalue)

                End If

      End If

    Next
```